# How to give individual containers a unique hostname within a single pod in Kubernetes?

Tags: python, docker, kubernetes, debian, google-kubernetes-engine

I have created 15 servers which contain the same machine learning program. However, each server has different arguments at the runtime. It is determined by the hostname. Each server also has a copy of a 5 1gb pkl files which contain training data.

So for example right now, I have created 15 servers in the cloud with the following names.

```
ml-node-1
ml-node-2
ml-node-3
..
ml-node-15
```

So when my program runs on `ml-node-1` it looks like this, `python3 mlscript.py $HOSTNAME.csv` and it will run `python3 mlscript.py ml-node-1.csv`. Each server will run the script which is meant for its hostname.

My problem is that I have to create 15 copies of the 5gb pkl data in each server before they are run. I find this very inefficient and costly therefore I am looking up Kubernetes as a solution. From the documentation, I can see that containers within a pod can share a persistent volume. This way I might be able to mitigate copying the 5gb pkl data 15 times.

However, I am trying to figure out the naming of the servers/containers. I figure that I would need 1 pod with a shared persistent volume and 15 containers. According to what I can understand from the documentation, https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/containers/container-environment/, all the containers within the pod will share the same hostname.

How do I differentiate them and give them specific hostnames so that I can still have a different argument running within each container? My docker images are the standard debian image with my machine learning script.

Comment: Using the hostname might not be the best choice in a scalable multi-host environment like Kubernetes.

Comment: @KlausD. any suggestions ? I Have never used this before so I have no idea where to start.

Comment: Have an `input` directory with available files to be picked up by your containers, which they rename and assign to themselves (with a randomly generated key, possibly) - any file not assigned can be picked up by a container for processing. That way you can scale your environment up and down in k8s as necessary (if you need more nodes/pods) and have a container process multiple files as they're still available.

Comment: @MatsLindh do you have an example of this? Sounds like it could work

Comment: It would be code that you write in your `mlscript.py` file, where it'd generate a unique key on startup and watch a directory for changes to pick up files from it as necessary (you can also use a message queue, but that might be overengineering for now). The python code would run forever, not exiting when it's done - in effect letting you configure a cluster of processors that handle files and that can be scaled through k8s.

Comment: @MatsLindh and im guessing the directory would be inside the shared persistent volume?

Comment: Correct, but in the future I'd suggest using a message queue and putting the files in a block storage (b2/s3/whatever internal tooling you have). That way you can post a new message to the queue and one of the nodes pick it up, download the file and process it.

Comment: @MatsLindh by blockstorage you mean like google cloud compute disks ? I didn't know those could be attached to the GKE

Comment: No, Google Cloud Storage would be Google's alternative for object storage (which was what I actually meant, not block storage - sorry!)

Comment: I agree that @MatsLindh's solution would be appropriate as K8s is not designed to allow for custom container hostnames within a single pod. Care to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than relying on custom hostnames for a scalable multi-host environment like Kubernetes (which is not designed to allow for this), as a more feasible solution ([suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65576309#comment115941183_65576309) by [MatsLindh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/137650)) you could write some code in your `mlscript.py` that generates a unique random key on startup and then watches an `input` directory for changes in a continuous loop: This directory would contain the available files to be picked up by the different containers, and the script would rename a given file with the generated key when it assigns it to the running server instance in the container, with "unassigned" files (not containing a key with the same format in the name) being considered available for other instances.

This would allow you to scale the workload up or down from Kubernetes as well as have several files processed by the same container instance.